# Jupyter notebook is corrupted due to merging conflict in git; how should I fix this?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

Long question short, i'm wokring on a project with a few members, and a merging conflict caused my jupyter notebook file to be unreadable: two persons pushed their local changes directly to the main branch to the git repo. Now when I attempt to open the jupyter notebook, this error popped up:

```
NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: \'{\\n "cells": [\\n {\\n "cell_type": "c...')
```

I wonder how I should fix this?

Comment: probably open with notepad and resolve the merge conflict.